# How to create Cover Flow in J2ME

Tags: java-me, nokia, coverflow

Is it possible to create iPhone like cover flow in J2ME (specially Nokia)?
If yes, what could be the logic to create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[J2ME Polish](http://www.enough.de/products/j2me-polish/) can be configured to provide lists in a cover-flow like UI (see [here](http://www.enough.de/products/j2me-polish/documentation/lush-ui/visual-guide/gui-screen-list.html)).

You might also be able to persuade [LWUIT](http://lwuit.java.net/) to produce something like coverflow, but I have less experience there.